# How does SIMD (avx) processing work? for example, if I want 10 32 bit floats how do i fit in a 256 bit avx vector?

Tags: c, simd, avx

I am learning about C avx intrinsics and I am wondering how this works.

I am familiar that I can do something like this:

```c
__m256 evens = _mm256_set_ps(2.0, 4.0, 6.0, 8.0, 10.0, 12.0, 14.0, 16.0);
```

Here I am storing 8 32 bit float numbers. So this is 256 bits.

But suppose I am writing a linear algebra library. Then how I do work with arbitrary number of vectors; for example how do I fit 10 32 bit floats in a avx vector?

If you can provide some examples, I will tremendously appreciated

Comment: You can't fit an arbitrary number in, it's always a fixed number, in this case *8 and 8 only*. If you need more, you'll need to do it in multiples of 8, or use AVX-512 which can, presumably, use multiples of 16. For your library you'll need to figure out which to use, and how many vectors you'll need based on the size of the input data.

Comment: This is too broad a question to answer fully on Stack Overflow. First, SIMD is most advantageous where there is lots of data, not ten elements at a time, so it is mostly written for software intended to process lots of data. Given that, to process ten elements, some choices are: (a) Process eight and then process another eight. The extra six might be unused data in the same array (padding) or other data in memory that you take care not to store over. (Load, do arithmetic, use special instructions to store just the first two).

Comment: (b) Load the first eight and the last eight, overlapping six. Do arithmetic and store the first eight and the last eight, partly redundantly. Requires load/store instructions that work with unaligned addresses. (c) Process the first eight with SIMD and the last two with scalar code.

Comment: (Going back to (a), if the start of an array is aligned, you can always load the last few elements using a whole-vector load because the memory beyond the array must have the same memory protection as the memory in the array, since page alignment is a superset of SIMD alignment. So you can always load whole vectors and perform operations on whole vectors. Then, when you need to store, if the hardware does not have partial-vector store instructions, you can store to a whole vector buffer and copy individual elements to the desired destination.)

Comment: Larger arrays need multiple vectors.  This style of SIMD uses fixed-length vectors that fit in vector registers, unlike Cray which gave the CPU a pointer and length and operated on memory.  See [Are there any problems for which SIMD outperforms Cray-style vectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72422491) for a discussion of the different ISA design choice.  (And some modern ISAs like AArch64 SVE and RISC-V vector extensions making the same machine code able to take advantage of different HW vector lengths, and with masking to aid handling the last partial vector.)

Comment: Near duplicate of [Do gcc vector extensions support variable length vectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65605561)

Comment: Correction, Cray did have large vector registers (instead of having cache).  It was earlier machines that had memory-to-memory SIMD with pointer + length (like x86's `rep movsd` for copying, but for ops like FP adding.)  See Dr. Bandwidth's answer on the comment I linked in my first comment.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: For 10 elements, you can use one `__m256` and one `__m128`, only overlapping by 2 elements.  Or load / store the `__m128` with `movsd` (64-bit), so only the low 2 elements matter; math will happen in the high two elements but you aren't using the results.  Adding or multiplying zeros is unlikely to trigger slowdowns for subnormals.  (And yes, you want `vmovsd xmm0, [rdi]` to zero-extend not `vmovlps xmm0, xmm0, [rdi]` to merge a new low half into an existing vector with a false dependency, even though `movsd` is nominally for scalar `double` so intrinsics need casting.)

Comment: @EricPostpischil: If you have a lot of separate 10-element problems, good use of SIMD can make it about 5x faster than than pure scalar.  And hopefully (unlike a single *huge* array), more of your loads/stores will hit in L1d or L2 cache.

Comment: thanks you all. i wasnt thinking concretely about 10 32 bit numbers. i was just asking how i can manipulate c intrinsics to work with arbitrary sized vectors and matrices

Comment: Yeah, I figured.  Look at how compilers auto-vectorize an arbitrary-length array, often with a scalar cleanup loop for leftover elements for a loop like `dst[i] = a[i] + b[i]` in a function taking args like `float *__restrict dst`, on https://godbolt.org/, for size `int n` or for some fixed odd size.  (Eric's suggestion of a partial overlapping vector is better for a case where the output doesn't overlap the input.  Especially for small element sizes like `uint8_t`, scalar cleanup can be a disaster.)

Comment: @EricPostpischil While I would never dispute your wisdom re Going back to (A) isn't loading past the end of the array still UB (in C)?

Comment: @AllanWind: No. C is a family of languages, of which the languages specified by the C standard are a subset. The C standard does not define the behavior of reading past the end of an array, and it also does not define SIMD operations. If you are using SIMD operations, you are using one of the C languages beyond or different from the C standard, and whether reading beyond an array (but within a page) is defined is up to the specific implementation of C you are using. E.g., with SIMD via inline assembly, the behavior is defined via the processor architecture.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I hear you re extension and appreciate your insight.  The C standard does say accessing and array out of bounds is undefined behavior (!= unspecified) (6.5.6p8), no?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, this is a broad question with a simple answer: Use loops and deal with element counts that are not multiples of your vector width as required.

Since an overly broad question invites an overly broad answer and I couldn't find a good reference on SO, maybe it is worthwhile to write up how to do vectorized loops.

## Scalar transformation loops

As an example, consider a simple `out[i] = in[i] * scale` loop. Of course a compiler is perfectly capable of vectorizing this on its own but it serves us well as a demonstration. The basic implementation looks like this:

```c
#include <immintrin.h>

#include <stddef.h>
/* using ptrdiff_t */

void vector_scale(float* out, const float* in, ptrdiff_t n, float scale)
{
    /* broadcast factor to all vector elements */
    const __m256 vscale = _mm256_set1_ps(scale);
    ptrdiff_t i;
    for(i = 0; i + 8 <= n; i += 8) {
        /* process 8 elements at a time */
        __m256 cur = _mm256_loadu_ps(in + i);
        cur = _mm256_mul_ps(cur, vscale);
        _mm256_storeu_ps(out + i, cur);
    }
    /* deal with last 0-7 elements */
    for(; i < n; ++i)
        out[i] = in[i] * scale;
}
```

### Aliasing issues

Vectorizing this loop had one consequence compared to the plain C version: Input and output may not overlap in such a way that storing the vector in one iteration overwrites the inputs in one of the following iterations. They may be direct aliases of one another (`in == out`) but you cannot have `in = out + 1` or similar. The auto-vectorized code would contain checks and fallbacks for that but if you manually vectorize, you normally don't bother and simply define this as a requirement.

If you want to prevent the compiler from making these checks and fallbacks plus integrate the requirement into the function declaration, use a [`restrict` pointer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/restrict).

```c
void vector_scale(
      float* restrict out, const float* in, ptrdiff_t n, float scale);
```

Alternatively, you can do the same checks in your manually vectorized code.

```c
inline _Bool pointers_interfere(
      const void* out, const void* in, size_t vectorsize)
{
    ptrdiff_t distance = (const char*) out - (const char*) in;
    return distance > 0 && (size_t) distance < vectorsize;
}
void vector_scale(float* out, const float* in, ptrdiff_t n, float scale)
{
    const __m256 vscale = _mm256_set1_ps(scale);
    ptrdiff_t i = 0;
    if(pointers_interfere(out, in, sizeof(__m256))) {
        for(; i < n; ++i) // unvectorized fallback
            out[i] = in[i] * scale;
        return;
    }
    ...
}
```

Some things to look out with this check:

1. It allows a direct alias of `out == in`
2. The code just prevents a difference from the scalar code. It doesn't make it correct. In this example, if `out == in + 8 && n > 8`, the result would still be nonsense; it's just the same nonsense you would get from the plain C version.
3. Technically, the pointer arithmetic in `out - in` is not well defined by the C standard if both pointers point to different arrays. However, we don't program for an abstract machine but specifically for x86-64 where we can assume to have a flat memory model. But keep this in mind when reusing that code on other platforms where this assumption may not hold, e.g. OpenCL kernels.

### Loop condition

I chose a loop of the form `for(i = 0; i + 8 <= n; i += 8)` since it is easy to read, hard to mess up (especially with unsigned types) and reasonably efficient. But it are not *the* most efficient way because the condition forces the compiler to compute `i+8` before the loop body when the body itself only needs `i`. A naive loop construction would waste a register on holding `i+8`. To understand how the compiler optimizes this and how we can help it, we have to differentiate between the loop condition being a signed type such as `ptrdiff_t` and an unsigned type such as `size_t`.

For signed types, the compiler is free to assume that `i+8` never over- or underflows and it can also work with signed comparisons. However, the compiler will not rewrite the condition into `i < n - 7`. This would fail if `n = LLONG_MIN` (or close to it) where `n-7` would wrap-around. Instead, GCC transforms the condition into something like `i < ((n - 8) & -8) + 8`. Things get more messy if the loop doesn't start at 0, as will be the case in some optimized loops further down. Therefore I don't recommend doing this optimization manually.

For unsigned types, fewer optimizations are possible and the wrap-around hazard occurs if `n < 8`. The compiler now turns the `i` into `i+8` inside the loop and makes every memory access with a fixed negative offset, e.g. `[rsi-32+rax*4]` instead of `[rsi+rax*4]`; or it does the naive code outlined above that wastes extra instructions and registers.

In both signed and unsigned cases, we can help the compiler along with some explicit checks. Something like this should do the trick:

```c
void vector_scale(float* out, const float* in, ptrdiff_t n, float scale)
{
    const __m256 vscale = _mm256_set1_ps(scale);
    ptrdiff_t i = 0;
    if(n > 7) {
        for(; i < n - 7; i += 8) {
            __m256 cur = _mm256_loadu_ps(in + i);
            cur = _mm256_mul_ps(cur, vscale);
            _mm256_storeu_ps(out + i, cur);
        }
    }
    for(; i < n; ++i)
        out[i] = in[i] * scale;
}
```

If you use signed loop counters like I do here, you probably get better code if you simply write `if(n <= 0) return;` early in the function and then you can do a simple `i < n - 7` condition without fear of wrap-around. However, for the benefit of the casual copy-and-paster, I make sure that all code below remains valid even if the loop counters are changed to unsigned types.

### Alignment

With SSE it [used to be very important](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12491578/whats-the-actual-effect-of-successful-unaligned-accesses-on-x86) that memory accesses were aligned to 16 byte boundaries. AVX generally handles unaligned access gracefully but you may still find performance improvements with aligned accesses. For AVX512, [alignment is again more important](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74785348/is-there-any-performance-difference-between-avx-512-mm512-load-epi64-and-mm). Whether aligning the loop is worth the extra code and runtime needs to be tested. Here I show how to do it. Since we have two arrays, we can only really align to one. When in doubt, it is usually better to align the output but this may also depend on the specific case and hardware.

Computing the aligned position is a prime candidate for micro-optimizations. The routine I show below is reasonably efficient and written to be readable and reusable. C++ templates or direct inline code can probably save some instructions. The idea is always the same: You round the memory address to the next higher multiple of the vector alignment. Then you figure out how many scalar entries that are and you check that the next alignment isn't beyond the end of the array.

```c
#include <stdint.h>
/* using uintptr_t */

inline void* next_aligned(const void* ptr, size_t alignment, const void* end)
{
    const uintptr_t pos = (uintptr_t) ptr;
    const uintptr_t alignedpos = (pos + alignment - 1) & -alignment;
    void* rtrn = (void*) alignedpos;
    return rtrn > end ? (void*) end : rtrn;
}

void vector_scale(float* out, const float* in, ptrdiff_t n, float scale)
{
    const __m256 vscale = _mm256_set1_ps(scale);
    const ptrdiff_t aligned =
          (float*) next_aligned(out, sizeof(__m256), out + n) - out;
    ptrdiff_t i;
    for(i = 0; i < aligned; ++i)
        out[i] = in[i] * scale;
    if(n > 7) {
        for(; i < n - 7; i += 8) {
            __m256 cur = _mm256_loadu_ps(in + i);
            cur = _mm256_mul_ps(cur, vscale);
            _mm256_store_ps(out + i, cur);
        }
    }
    for(; i < n; ++i)
        out[i] = in[i] * scale;
}
```

### Vectorizing head and tail

Instead of scalar loops, we can use smaller vector sizes to deal with the misaligned front and the remaining tail elements. This has the added benefit of stopping the compiler from auto-vectorizing these short loops. Whether this is worth it needs to be tested. For example Oracle Java's compiler [seems to think it is not worth it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76644132/understanding-jits-rewrite-of-a-for-loop/76654044#76654044).

```c
void vector_scale(float* out, const float* in, ptrdiff_t n, float scale)
{
    const __m256 vscale = _mm256_set1_ps(scale);
    const ptrdiff_t aligned =
          (float*) next_aligned(out, sizeof(__m256), out + n) - out;
    ptrdiff_t i, tail;
    if(n <= 0) /* otherwise bit-tests fail if negative */
        return;
    if((i = aligned & 1) != 0)
        out[0] = in[0] * scale;
    if(aligned & 2) {
        /* process 2 elements */
        __m128 cur = _mm_loadl_pi(_mm_undefined_ps(), (const __m64*) (in + i));
        cur = _mm_mul_ps(cur, _mm256_castps256_ps128(vscale));
        _mm_storel_pi((__m64*) (out + i), cur);
        i += 2;
    }
    if(aligned & 4) {
        /* process 4 elements */
        __m128 cur = _mm_loadu_ps(in + i);
        cur = _mm_mul_ps(cur, _mm256_castps256_ps128(vscale));
        _mm_store_ps(out + i, cur);
        i += 4;
    }
    if(n > 7) {
        for(; i < n - 7; i += 8) {
            /* process 8 elements at a time */
            __m256 cur = _mm256_loadu_ps(in + i);
            cur = _mm256_mul_ps(cur, vscale);
            _mm256_store_ps(out + i, cur);
        }
    }
    tail = n - i;
    if(tail & 4) {
        __m128 cur = _mm_load_ps(in + i);
        cur = _mm_mul_ps(cur, _mm256_castps256_ps128(vscale));
        _mm_store_ps(out + i, cur);
        i += 4;
    }
    if(tail & 2) {
        __m128 cur = _mm_loadl_pi(_mm_undefined_ps(), (const __m64*) (in + i));
        cur = _mm_mul_ps(cur, _mm256_castps256_ps128(vscale));
        _mm_storel_pi((__m64*) (out + i), cur);
        i += 2;
    }
    if(tail & 1) {
        out[i] = in[i] * scale;
        ++i;
    }
}
```

### Overlapping head and tail

Instead of using smaller vectors, we can apply a simple trick: We do one misaligned iteration for the first 8 entries. Then, instead of skipping forward 8 elements, we skip forward to the aligned position. This means the first aligned iteration will partially overlap with the unaligned iteration but this is much cheaper than doing the partial processing we did above. We can then do the same for the tail with an unaligned iteration starting at `n - 8`. This style of processing has three more requirements compared to the loops above.

1. We need at least one full vector full of data. We have to include a special-case for small vectors
2. The processing needs to be position-independent within the vector register. Meaning for every scalar `in[i]` the position within the vector register must not matter (this can occur with shuffle instructions, for example)
3. Input and output cannot alias each other, otherwise you would apply the same operation twice on the overlapping elements

```c
void vector_scale(
      float* restrict out, const float* in, ptrdiff_t n, float scale)
{
    const __m256 vscale = _mm256_set1_ps(scale);
    const ptrdiff_t aligned =
          (float*) next_aligned(out + 1, sizeof(__m256), out + n) - out;
    ptrdiff_t i, tail = n - 8;
    if(n < 8) {
        /* special case for small inputs */
        if(n <= 0)
            return;
        if((i = n & 1) != 0)
            out[0] = in[0] * scale;
        if(n & 2) {
            __m128 cur = _mm_loadl_pi(_mm_undefined_ps(), (const __m64*) (in + i));
            cur = _mm_mul_ps(cur, _mm256_castps256_ps128(vscale));
            _mm_storel_pi((__m64*) (out + i), cur);
            i += 2;
        }
        if(n & 4) {
            __m128 cur = _mm_loadu_ps(in + i);
            cur = _mm_mul_ps(cur, _mm256_castps256_ps128(vscale));
            _mm_storeu_ps(out + i, cur);
            i += 4;
        }
        return;
    }
    {  /* first iteration, potentially misaligned */
        __m256 cur = _mm256_loadu_ps(in);
        cur = _mm256_mul_ps(cur, vscale);
        _mm256_storeu_ps(out, cur);
    }
    for(i = aligned; i < tail; i += 8) {
        __m256 cur = _mm256_loadu_ps(in + i);
        cur = _mm256_mul_ps(cur, vscale);
        _mm256_store_ps(out + i, cur);
    }
    {   /* last iteration */
        __m256 cur = _mm256_loadu_ps(in + tail);
        cur = _mm256_mul_ps(cur, vscale);
        _mm256_storeu_ps(out + tail, cur);
    }
}
```

Please note the slight change from `next_aligned(out, …)` to `next_aligned(out + 1, …)`. Otherwise a properly aligned output array would result in one fully redundant iteration.

## Reduction loops

The sample above covers simple transformations but what about reductions? Let's explore a simple vector dot product: `sum(left[i] * right[i])`. As above, we start simple and then optimize the code iteratively. I assume we have AVX and FMA instructions available for this one.

```c
float vector_dot(const float* left, const float* right, ptrdiff_t n)
{
    __m256 vsum = _mm256_setzero_ps();
    __m128 high_half, low_half;
    float headsum, tailsum = 0.f;
    ptrdiff_t i = 0;
    if(n > 7) {
        for(; i < n - 7; i += 8) {
            const __m256 lefti = _mm256_loadu_ps(left + i);
            const __m256 righti = _mm256_loadu_ps(right + i);
            vsum = _mm256_fmadd_ps(lefti, righti, vsum);
        }
    }
    /* Reduce 8 elements to 4 */
    high_half = _mm256_extractf128_ps(vsum, 1);
    low_half = _mm256_castps256_ps128(vsum);
    low_half = _mm_add_ps(low_half, high_half);
    /* Reduce 4 to 2 */
    high_half = _mm_movehl_ps(low_half, low_half);
    low_half = _mm_add_ps(low_half, high_half);
    /* Reduce 2 to 1 */
    high_half = _mm_movehdup_ps(low_half);
    low_half = _mm_add_ss(low_half, high_half);
    headsum = _mm_cvtss_f32(low_half);
    /* Process last 0-7 elements */
    for(; i < n; ++i)
        tailsum += left[i] * right[i];
    return headsum + tailsum;
}
```

### Loop-carried dependency chains

The main loop of our reduction has one critical issue: The FMA instruction depends on the value of the previous iteration. On most systems, FMA has a latency of 4 cycles (though older CPUs such as AMD Zen2 or Intel Broadwell use 5 cycles). This means, at best we get one iteration every 4 cycles instead of one per cycle. To avoid this, we have to interleave at least 4 FMA dependency chains; basically keeping four partial sums. What makes this extra painful is that you cannot rely on inner loops for this unless you know your compiler unrolls those (GCC doesn't).

```c
float vector_dot(const float* left, const float* right, ptrdiff_t n)
{
    __m256 vsum1 = _mm256_setzero_ps();
    __m256 vsum2 = vsum1, vsum3 = vsum1, vsum4 = vsum1;
    __m128 high_half, low_half;
    float headsum, tailsum = 0.f;
    ptrdiff_t i = 0;
    if(n > 31) {
        for(; i < n - 31; i += 32) {
            __m256 lefti = _mm256_loadu_ps(left + i);
            __m256 righti = _mm256_loadu_ps(right + i);
            vsum1 = _mm256_fmadd_ps(lefti, righti, vsum1);
            lefti = _mm256_loadu_ps(left + i + 8);
            righti = _mm256_loadu_ps(right + i + 8);
            vsum2 = _mm256_fmadd_ps(lefti, righti, vsum2);
            lefti = _mm256_loadu_ps(left + i + 16);
            righti = _mm256_loadu_ps(right + i + 16);
            vsum3 = _mm256_fmadd_ps(lefti, righti, vsum3);
            lefti = _mm256_loadu_ps(left + i + 24);
            righti = _mm256_loadu_ps(right + i + 24);
            vsum4 = _mm256_fmadd_ps(lefti, righti, vsum4);
        }
    }
    if(n - i >= 16) {
        __m256 lefti = _mm256_loadu_ps(left + i);
        __m256 righti = _mm256_loadu_ps(right + i);
        vsum1 = _mm256_fmadd_ps(lefti, righti, vsum1);
        lefti = _mm256_loadu_ps(left + i + 8);
        righti = _mm256_loadu_ps(right + i + 8);
        vsum2 = _mm256_fmadd_ps(lefti, righti, vsum2);
        i += 16;
    }
    if(n - i >= 8) {
        __m256 lefti = _mm256_loadu_ps(left + i);
        __m256 righti = _mm256_loadu_ps(right + i);
        vsum1 = _mm256_fmadd_ps(lefti, righti, vsum1);
        i += 8;
    }
    /* Reduce 32 to 16 */
    vsum1 = _mm256_add_ps(vsum1, vsum3);
    vsum2 = _mm256_add_ps(vsum2, vsum4);
    /* Reduce 16 to 8 */
    vsum1 = _mm256_add_ps(vsum1, vsum2);
    /* Reduce 8 elements to 4 */
    high_half = _mm256_extractf128_ps(vsum1, 1);
    low_half = _mm256_castps256_ps128(vsum1);
    low_half = _mm_add_ps(low_half, high_half);
    /* Reduce 4 to 2 */
    high_half = _mm_movehl_ps(low_half, low_half);
    low_half = _mm_add_ps(low_half, high_half);
    /* Reduce 2 to 1 */
    high_half = _mm_movehdup_ps(low_half);
    low_half = _mm_add_ss(low_half, high_half);
    headsum = _mm_cvtss_f32(low_half);
    /* Process last 0-7 elements */
    for(; i < n; ++i)
        tailsum += left[i] * right[i];
    return headsum + tailsum;
}
```

### Further optimizations

The following optimizations are possible but will not be covered in detail:

1. The first iteration does not need a full multiply-add since we only add zero. We can peel the first iteration off and turn it into a simple multiplication. However, this step is particularly sensitive to the length of the input data. It's only really relevant if the vectors are short. But then you have to balance the number of branches you use to initialize the partial sums with the cost of those branches (and potential mispredictions). It might be necessary to make specialized code paths for short vectors.
2. The last 0-7 elements can be vectorized. Possibly something like this:

```c
    ptrdiff_t tail;
    if(n <= 0) /* check so bit tests don't fail with negative n */
        return 0.f;
    ... /* main loop */
    tail = n - i;
    /* Reduce 8 elements to 4 */
    high_half = _mm256_extractf128_ps(vsum1, 1);
    low_half = _mm256_castps256_ps128(vsum1);
    low_half = _mm_add_ps(low_half, high_half);
    if(tail & 4) {
        __m128 lefti = _mm_loadu_ps(left + i);
        __m128 righti = _mm_loadu_ps(right + i);
        low_half = _mm_fmadd_ps(lefti, righti, low_half);
        i += 4;
    }
    if(tail & 2) {
        __m128 lefti = _mm_loadl_pi(_mm_setzero_ps(), (const __m64*) (left + i));
        __m128 righti = _mm_loadl_pi(_mm_setzero_ps(), (const __m64*) (right + i));
        low_half = _mm_fmadd_ps(lefti, righti, low_half);
        i += 2;
    }
    /* Reduce 2 to 1 */
    high_half = _mm_movehdup_ps(low_half);
    low_half = _mm_add_ss(low_half, high_half);
    float sum = _mm_cvtss_f32(low_half);
    if(tail & 1)
        sum += left[i] * right[i];
    return sum;
```

3. We can align one of the input vectors. Which vector to choose is hard to predict. With SSE instructions it might make sense to inspect the generated code to see where proper alignment allowed either the use of short `movaps` instructions or folding an aligned load into an arithmetic instruction.

## AVX-512

With AVX-512's mask registers, things get a lot easier. The alignment and tail loops can simply be implemented via masked loads and stores.

```c
void vector_scale(float* out, const float* in, ptrdiff_t n, float scale)
{
    const __m512 vscale = _mm512_set1_ps(scale);
    const ptrdiff_t aligned =
          (float*) next_aligned(out + 1, sizeof(__m512), out + n) - out;
    __mmask16 mask = _cvtu32_mask16((1 << (unsigned) aligned) - 1);
    ptrdiff_t i = aligned, tail;
    __m512 cur;
    if(n <= 0)
        return;
    cur = _mm512_maskz_loadu_ps(mask, in);
    cur = _mm512_mul_ps(cur, vscale);
    _mm512_mask_storeu_ps(out, mask, cur);
    if(n > 15) {
        for(; i < n - 15; i += 16) {
            cur = _mm512_load_ps(in + i);
            cur = _mm512_mul_ps(cur, vscale);
            _mm512_store_ps(out + i, cur);
        }
    }
    tail = n - i;
    mask = _cvtu32_mask16((1 << (unsigned) tail) - 1);
    cur = _mm512_maskz_load_ps(mask, in + i);
    cur = _mm512_mul_ps(cur, vscale);
    _mm512_mask_store_ps(out + i, mask, cur);
}
```

One thing to look out for when adapting this code is the mask generation: If you need a `__mmask32`, the intermediate `1 << ones` needs to be a 64 bit type to avoid overflowing if `ones == 32` and for `__mmask64` you would need `__int128`. Especially in the second case a better option is `__mask64 mask = _cvtu64_mask64((uint64_t) -1 >> (64 - ones))`.

As usual with AVX-512, choosing 512 bit or 256 bit vectors requires testing and knowledge of the specific hardware since large vectors [may or may not reduce clock rate](https://travisdowns.github.io/blog/2020/08/19/icl-avx512-freq.html), potentially affecting other parts of the code, and it may have [other limiting factors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74152102/why-does-gcc-auto-vectorization-for-tigerlake-use-ymm-not-zmm-registers).

Comment: *The auto-vectorized code would contain checks and fallbacks for [overlap]* - To avoid that, use `float *restrict out, const float *restrict in` to promise to the compiler that they don't overlap.  (If you violate that promise, you have a correctness problem.)  Overall nice answer; thanks for writing up this SIMD loop tutorial.

Comment: `i + 8 <= n` - that loop condition should optimize ok for signed types (because compilers know signed overflow is UB), but IIRC when using `size_t i` and `n` I've had better results with `i < (n-(8-1))`, which the compiler can still be sure isn't an infinite loop for any `n`.  And it's not tempted into doing the same pointer increment at 2 places in the same loop; any extra work (to compute a loop upper bound or preferably an end-pointer) is outside the loop.  `n - (unroll-1)` reduces to `n` for `unroll=1`, that's how you verify you're remembering the correct expression.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for the feedback! I rewrote parts of the answer and the loops. Part of the issue is that I want the code to remain correct even if people copy it and change the types to unsigned. I think I found a decent compromise with the extended discussion on the topic I included

Comment: Oh right, yeah `i < (n-(unroll-1))` is only safe inside an `if (n >= unroll)`, that there's at least one full vector.  So probably worth checking how compilers do with exact loop you wrote.  If it's a non-problem these days, then great, keep the `i+unroll <= n`.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/M3Gvfb73T - It seems that GCC13 at least does a good job with both idioms, arguably better with yours for `size_t` since it doesn't have to `lea` for the possibly-wrapping subtraction. Clang  unrolls further, doing multiple vectors per loop so it has to check stuff, like check for overlap and fall back to an unrolled scalar loop.  But things don't seem better or worse with `i < n - (unroll-1)`; both using indexed addressing modes for example, defeating half the benefit of unrolling on Intel CPUs.  ([Micro fusion and addressing modes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26046634))

Comment: @Homer512 thank you so much! do you have any book recommendations to keep learning this stuff. im going to study your answer here but im wondering if theres  any books you recommend. thanks for your great answer

Comment: @chez93 Honestly, i learned by reading [Peter's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/224132/peter-cordes?tab=answers) and from [Agner Fog's writing](https://www.agner.org/optimize/)

Comment: @Homer512 thanks a lot for your answer. Im going to extrapolate from your answer to do basic linear algebra! Thanks