# Are there aggregate operations in x86 AVX?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, sse, avx, reduction

I am try to writing a simple game and I need to study some x86 assemble for vector operation. Use xmm as 4 packed single-precision floating-point, are there any aggregate operations? Such as:

"MAXPS" to calculate the max of the 4 fp32. (used on Chebyshev Distance or so on)

"SUMPS" to calculate the sum of the 4 fp32. (used on dot product or vector magnitude)

Comment: `maxps` is an instruction, but it takes 4 separate maximums not the maximum of 4 elements. For horizontal operations see for example [Fastest way to do horizontal SSE vector sum (or other reduction)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6996764/555045). If reasonably possible you should avoid most horizontal operations.

Comment: Only a couple, like `psadbw` (sum of absolute differences in groups of 8 bytes), and `phminposuw` (horizontal min of u16 elements).  And pairwise `pmaddwd` does widening vertical multiply and adds pairs of products within the 32-bit result elements, like `pmaddubsw` for 8x8 => 16-bit.  I don't really count `haddps` / `phaddd` because real CPUs run them as 2 shuffle uops and a vertical add, or worse on some CPUs, so no real HW support for even pairwise horizontal addition; only useful with 2 different inputs as part of a transpose-and-accumulate type of operation.

Comment: To spell it out differently: This kind of "horizontal" operation is pretty slow and limited. In a reduction like a sum or a max-over-array, you use it as the very last step after accumulating partial results in each of the four vector elements

Comment: If you want to search for instructions, I recommend going to the [intel intrinsics guide](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html), even if you don't want to use the intrinsics themselves, they list the assembly instruction. Since you mentioned a dot product, I just wrote one [as part of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77574422/how-does-simd-avx-processing-work-for-example-if-i-want-10-32-bit-floats-how/77586123#77586123)

Answer (score 1):

TLDR: There are a few reduction instructions, but usually you should follow: [Fastest way to do horizontal SSE vector sum (or other reduction)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6996764)

---

The only floating-point instructions (I'm aware of) which do horizontal reductions are

- [`haddps`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/haddps)/[`haddpd`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/haddpd): These add up two adjacent values each from two input registers and stack them into one output register (with the usual quirk, that AVX256 is like two separate SSE/AVX128 operations). Do not use these, if you want to reduce a single register to a scalar (see the linked answer above).
- [`dpps`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/dpps)/[`dppd`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/dppd): Calculate a dot-product of (up to) 4 elements (`dpps`) or up to two elements (`dppd`). This is often only worth using if your primary goal is small binary size, or with special cases of masking input/output. The `dppd` instruction apparently is not even ported to 256bit at all. Also, never use this as building block for a large dot-products (these should use only `fma` instructions in the main-loop with a horizontal reduction at the end).

Answer (score 0):

One non-loopng, non-branching way to get the maximum float value of an SSE vector would be something like the following.

```
inline float _mm_hmax_ps(__m128 arg) {
  // Returns the maximum 32 bit float value in arg.
  // Requires SSE.
  __m128 temp, temp2;
  temp = _mm_shuffle_ps(arg, arg, 78);  // 78 = 01001110b
  temp = _mm_max_ps(arg, temp);
  temp2 = _mm_shuffle_ps(temp, temp, 165); // 165 = 10100101b
  temp2 = _mm_max_ps(temp2, temp);
  return _mm_cvtss_f32(temp2);
}
```

...and an AVX version is as follows.

```
inline float _mm256_hmax_ps(__m256 arg) {
  // Returns the maximum 32 bit float value in arg.
  // Requires AVX1 & SSE1. 
  __m128 temp128u, temp128l;  
  __m256 temp, temp2;
  temp = _mm256_shuffle_ps(arg, arg, 78);  // 78 = 01001110b
  temp = _mm256_max_ps(arg, temp);
  temp2 = _mm256_shuffle_ps(temp, temp, 165); // 165 = 10100101b
  temp = _mm256_max_ps(temp2, temp);
  temp128u = _mm256_extractf128_ps(temp, 1);
  temp128l = _mm256_extractf128_ps(temp, 0);
  temp128u = _mm_max_ps(temp128u, temp128l);
  return _mm_cvtss_f32(temp128u);
}
```

Comment: C allows hex and binary integer literals, like `0b01001110`.  Or you can use the macro `_MM_SHUFFLE(1,0, 3,2)` to express numbers as four 2-bit fields.  (It's defined in `immintrin.h`).  Anything other than decimal would take less mental effort to see what they do.  In C++ you can even do `0b01'00'11'10`. But normally I use `_MM_SHUFFLE` in C/C++, only using binary with separators in NASM like `shufps xmm0, xmm0, 0b01_00_11_10`

Comment: Also, as shown in [Fastest way to do horizontal SSE vector sum (or other reduction)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6996764), doing the second shuffle with `__m128 temp2 _mm_movehl_ps(arg, temp);` can save a `movaps` instruction by reusing an old register as a separate destination for the high half, when compiling without AVX.

Comment: @PeterCordes The code I posted is tested and working. I tried the substitution you suggested and it broke the function, so I didn't adopt your suggestion. I didn't understand why your suggestion broke the function until I dug a bit into it just now. You have to change the immediate in the first shuffle to 0xb1 to make it work with movehl as you suggested. I get the same number of instructions though either way, and they benchmark exactly the same. Is there any reason to change it I don't know about? I haven't counted the byte code yet,... anything else?

Comment: Right yes, `movhlps` requires the first shuffle set up for it.  Did you compile with clang? It pessimises the code, using `movaps` + `unpckhpd` instead of `movhlps` for `_mm_movehl_ps`.   https://godbolt.org/z/zaqv77fKz shows the asm difference with GCC / MSVC saving a `movaps`.  (Without AVX, which avoids the need for any `movaps`.  Although `vmovhlps` is still smaller machine code by 2 bytes than `vpermilps imm8`.)  Microbenchmarks will only show the benefit if you bottleneck on front-end throughput (or ROB capacity / out-of-order window size), not latency or shuffle throughput.

Comment: (There is also a latency benefit to avoiding `movaps` on Intel before Ivy Bridge, and AMD before Bulldozer, i.e. for CPUs which don't do mov elimination for XMM regs.
 [Can x86's MOV really be "free"? Why can't I reproduce this at all?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44169342) .  Ice Lake disable mov-elim in microcode, but only for GPRs, not vector regs, so this only affects obsolete CPUs, and low-power Intel Silvermont; apparently even Goldmont has mov-elim for XMM.  But the throughput cost of running another instruction is still there, although not always the bottleneck.)

Comment: @PeterCordes I used gcc 9.4 with -O3 -msse. I didn't try clang or any other compiler. After improving my micro-benchmarking, I found my version was actually faster by a couple of cycles on my old Nehalem laptop. I don't know why that would be. I don't know CPU architectures like you do. It could be totally different on newer hardware. I've got piles of old junk hardware, I think I need to update some. I think there's some value in keeping it similar to my AVX function and there's no movehl equivalent in AVX. Thanks for your input.

Comment: I'd definitely expect my version to be faster on Nehalem, if it compiled the way I expected, at least for latency.  (Throughput will bottleneck on shuffle uops for pot 5).  But you said you got the same number of total instructions, which surprises me.  Can you share a godbolt link with your benchmark code?  Nehalem is P6-family, no uop cache, although it does have a 28 uop loop buffer like SnB family.  In larger loops, code alignment quirks can lead to different front-end bottlenecks; smaller is on average faster but not always. It also has register-read stalls.

Comment: *there's no movehl equivalent in AVX.* - Unless you want the `max` broadcasted to all elements, a good strategy is to narrow to `__m128` as the first step then call `_mm_hmax_ps` (which will inline with `vmovhlps xmm`).  See `hsum256_ps_avx` in my linked hsum answer.  This is good for Alder Lake E-cores and Zen 1 (where 256-bit ops cost 2 uops).  Otherwise sure, doing the lower-latency in-lane shuffles first might have a tiny advantage in letting more uops leave the scheduler a couple cycles sooner.  For 256-bit, `vunpckhpd` moves down the high half of each lane, like we wanted with `movhlps`

Comment: @PeterCordes FWIW, here is the code I used to benchmark https://github.com/FastAsChuff/Micro-Benchmarking-Programs/blob/main/simdhmaxbmark.c. The difference is not so great on my server, but the shuffle is still faster. I'd be interested to hear what result you get if you run it on your Skylake CPU or whatever you have now. Thanks.

Comment: I see the difference.  `_mm_max_ps` is *not* commutative (because of NaN), and your way was forcing GCC to use an extra `movaps`, not saving insns after all.  And when it inlines into `main`, for some reason there's an extra `shufps` mixed in with the emulated FP to u64 code (bad choice, no HW support for that until AVX-512.)  Oh, that's the `vec = _mm_shuffle_ps(vec, vec, 78);` in your main loop.  GCC does common-subexpression elimination between it and the first shuffle of this iteration's `hmax_ps`, but only for the version that starts with that, giving it an unfair throughput advantage.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/hY3YcPaqr is a fixed version that has one less `movaps` in the loop with the `movhlps` version.  It's hopefully faster on Nehalem, if front-end throughput is a bottleneck. It's also lower latency but OoO exec hides that. (I used `vec = _mm_xor_ps(vec, set1(-1.23))` as a chain instruction, low latency and also port 5 only in Nehalem, and definitely can't CSE with any of the other ops.  And `junk = (int64_t)max` so we're not measuring throughput of float to u64 conversion with a branch on the FP value to fix up the integer result of FP to i64 conversion.)

Comment: After inlining into the loop, GCC is still still copying the original `vec` twice, but that's once for `shufps`, once because of  `xorps`.  It does `movhlps` into one of the copies it made, because it needs the original unmodified.  So there's maybe not as much to save here.  Because your `_mm_hmax_ps` wants to overwrite `arg`, not the first `shufps` result, as the spare register. Seems no way around that, my earlier Godbolt link overwrites the incoming arg with the first maxps (I tried it anyway to spot that: https://godbolt.org/z/qY4PEW9Pe).

Comment: I think (but not 100% certain) both ways benefit equally from the vector input being "dead" (not needed) after we get the max.  You normally don't keep mutating the same vector after taking its hmax, so that's the more common case.

Comment: On my Skylake, the code in https://godbolt.org/z/Yn6n7v8Mj (with the repeat count bumped by a factor of 1000, to 1000000000, so the main work matches warmup), with GCC13.2 the `gcc -O2 -DUSE_MOVHLPS` version runs about 3.16 TSC reference cycles or `3.08` core clock per iteration (3.9GHz core clock with these EPP settings, 4008 MHz TSC; inconvenient way to time that depends on CPU power management; I usually use perf on a static executable with multiple runs of the program acting as warm-up.) vs. 3.35 TSCs or `3.26` core clocks for the version without movhlps. Taking best of multiple runs

Comment: I noticed `cvtss2si r64, xmm` is 3 uops on Skylake, up from 2 on Haswell, 1 on Nehalem.  Including one for port 5, which put it close to a shuffle port bottleneck.  (SKL can run `xorps` on any port, unlike earlier where it's only port 5).  Changing the code to make the `junk |=` part more efficient, I first tried `(unsigned)(int32_t)max` but GCC chooses to convert to 64-bit and truncate with `mov eax,eax`, as if it was converting directly to `unsigned`.  So I changed `junk` to 32-bit. https://godbolt.org/z/sWoWrGsbz has results in a comment: 2.97c / iter with movhlps, 3.015c / iter without.