# Fast int32_t dot product of two C++ integer vectors using AVX is not faster

Tags: c++, optimization, avx, avx2, dot-product

I've implemented a simple dot product of two vectors :

```
int dotProductNoAVX(const std::vector<int>& vec1, const std::vector<int>& vec2)
{
    // Calculate dot product using simple for loops
    int dotProduct = 0;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < vec1.size(); ++i)
    {
        dotProduct += vec1[i] * vec2[i];
    }

    return dotProduct;
}
```

And implemented a "faster" version using AVX256 :

```
// Function to calculate the dot product of two vectors using AVX intrinsics
int dotProductAVX(const std::vector<int>& vec1, const std::vector<int>& vec2)
{
    // Ensure the size of vectors is a multiple of 8 (size of AVX register)
    std::size_t size = vec1.size();
    std::size_t avxSize = size / 8 * 8;

    // Initialize variables for AVX operations
    __m256i sum = _mm256_setzero_si256();

    // Perform AVX dot product
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < avxSize; i += 8)
    {
        __m256i vec1_part = _mm256_loadu_si256(reinterpret_cast<const __m256i*>(&vec1[i]));
        __m256i vec2_part = _mm256_loadu_si256(reinterpret_cast<const __m256i*>(&vec2[i]));
        sum = _mm256_add_epi32(sum, _mm256_mullo_epi32(vec1_part, vec2_part));
    }

    // Sum the remaining elements using scalar operations
    int result[8];
    _mm256_storeu_si256(reinterpret_cast<__m256i*>(result), sum);
    int dotProduct = result[0] + result[1] + result[2] + result[3] + result[4] + result[5] + result[6] + result[7];

    // Sum the remaining elements using scalar operations
    for (std::size_t i = avxSize; i < size; ++i)
    {
        dotProduct += vec1[i] * vec2[i];
    }

    return dotProduct;
}
```

I get roughly the same speed.
sometimes the AVX is 10-20% faster.

I'm using VS2017 and I7-12700k (which I support AVX as far as i understand)

I've even tried to profile it, but nothing too suspicious.
The only thing is that this line :

```
    int dotProduct = result[0] + result[1] + result[2] + result[3] + result[4] + result[5] + result[6] + result[7];
```

takes long time, but not sure how to improve it

I'm testing using this main function,

```
std::vector<int> generateRandomVector(std::size_t size)
{
    std::vector<int> randomVector;
    randomVector.reserve(size);

    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(1, 100);

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        randomVector.push_back(distribution(gen));
    }

    return randomVector;
}

int main()
{
    // Specify the size of the random vectors
    std::size_t vectorSize = 100;
    int iterations = 1000000;
    // Generate two random vectors
    std::vector<int> vector1 = generateRandomVector(vectorSize);
    std::vector<int> vector2 = generateRandomVector(vectorSize);

    // Measure time for dot product with AVX
    int resultAVX;
    auto startAVX = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
        resultAVX = dotProductAVX(vector1, vector2);
    //resultAVX = dotProductAVX512(vector1, vector2);
    auto endAVX = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double> durationAVX = endAVX - startAVX;

    int resultNoAVX;
    auto startNoAVX = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
        resultNoAVX = dotProductNoAVX(vector1, vector2);
    auto endNoAVX = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double> durationNoAVX = endNoAVX - startNoAVX;

    // Display the result and time taken
    std::cout << "Dot product without AVX: " << resultNoAVX << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Time taken without AVX: " << durationNoAVX.count() << " seconds" << std::endl;



    // Display the result and time taken
    std::cout << "Dot product with AVX: " << resultAVX << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Time taken with AVX: " << durationAVX.count() << " seconds" << std::endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How about ‘std::inner_product’?

Comment: You have short vectors so an efficient horizontal sum is important.  [Fastest way to do horizontal SSE vector sum (or other reduction)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6996764) and specifically `hsum_8x32` in [Fastest method to calculate sum of all packed 32-bit integers using AVX512 or AVX2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60108658) .  MSVC might be auto-vectorizing the scalar version with at least SSE2, or with 128-bit `pmulld` (SSE4.1) or 256-bit with AVX2 depending on compiler options.

Comment: I also wouldn't trust those benchmark loops not to optimize away work.  `int resultAVX` isn't `volatile`, and even if it was, the compiler could still do the dot product once outside the loop and then just `mov [rsp+12], eax` as the entire loop body other than dec/jnz.  Perhaps adding something like `vector1[64 + (i & 31)]++` could stop the compiler from optimizing away the dot product, if it is.  [Idiomatic way of performance evaluation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60291987)

Comment: MSVC does auto-vectorize: https://godbolt.org/z/frW4x5KaP shows with no arch options MSVC19.37 defaulting to using SSE4.1 `pmulld`, and a somewhat clunky hsum.  Or with AVX2 using 256-bit versions, but using `vphaddd` for the horizontal sum, rather inefficient.  (Also note that for 100-element vectors, that leaves 4 elements of scalar cleanup for 8-element vectors; 100 % 8 = 4.  A cleanup strategy that considered one 4-element vector before doing the last 3 scalar could be good, adding in after the first reduction step of the 256-bit vector.)

Comment: Other strategies are possible for handling the last 0..7 elements, or 1..8 depending where you end your loop.  Like a masked load that partially overlaps, e.g. [Vectorizing with unaligned buffers: using VMASKMOVPS: generating a mask from a misalignment count? Or not using that insn at all](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34306933) .   [How does SIMD (avx) processing work? for example, if I want 10 32 bit floats how do i fit in a 256 bit avx vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77574422) has some ideas on cleanup strategy, but mostly only applicable to `dst[i] = f(src[i])` non-reduction loops.

Comment: Seems you got lucky with your benchmark: https://godbolt.org/z/9M3zsKE4W shows MSVC `-O2` and `-O2 -arch:AVX2` choosing not to inline your dot-product functions, and actually calling them inside the loop.  So other than warm-up effects, your benchmark is probably fine.  (Pinning it to a P-core or an E-core would also be a good idea, though, for consistent benchmarking on your hybrid CPU.  Also, `std::vector<int>` won't reliably allocate 32-byte aligned memory; IDK whether it tends to in practice or not on MSVC.  Depending on your real use-case, you might want to align your data.)

Comment: The `result[0] + result[1] + ...` is even worse than you'd expect: it "optimizes" the store / scalar access into shuffles like `vextractf128 xmm0, ymm2, 1` / `vpextrd eax, xmm2, 1` / `add ebx, eax`.  Or worse, compiling without `-arch:AVX2`, `vextractf128 xmm0, ymm2, 1` / `vpsrldq xmm0, xmm0, 4` / `vmovd   eax, xmm0`.  Store and scalar reload would be faster for accessing each element one at a time.  But still slower than an efficient hsum with manual shuffling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL:DR: your cleanup is even worse than what MSVC does when auto-vectorizing, and that's significant for short vectors.  Optimizing your cleanup code should make a dot product that's a bit faster than MSVC's auto-vectorized code, at the cost of specializing it for a specific SIMD width.

For larger sizes, unrolling the main loop by 2 would help especially on Intel CPUs where `vpmulld` is 2 uops, or 3 with a memory source operand.

---

Your benchmark is probably valid; even though the compiler *could* hoist the work out of the repeat loop<sup>1</sup>, MSVC 19.37 chooses not to inline the dot product functions so that doesn't happen.

MSVC auto-vectorizes the scalar version (with SSE4.1 `pmulld` with `-O2` without any arch options, or with `-O2 -arch:AVX2` using `vpmulld ymm` like your intrinsics.)  MSVC's auto-vectorized version unrolls the loop by 2 vectors, which is probably good.  In your manual loop, front-end throughput is the bottleneck even on [6-wide](https://www.anandtech.com/show/17047/the-intel-12th-gen-core-i912900k-review-hybrid-performance-brings-hybrid-complexity/5) Alder Lake P-cores (Golden Cove).  Hopefully you're pinning your benchmark to a P core or an E core, depending on which one you want to measure.

**Your vectors are short (only 100 elements) so scalar cleanup of leftover elements, and the horizontal sum, are important factors.**  100 elements is only 12.5 vectors of 8 elements each.

The `result[0] + result[1] + ...` compiles even worse than you'd expect (**[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGe1wAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxCCSABykAA6oCoRODB7evnrJqY4CQSHhLFEx8baY9vkMQgRMxASZPn5cFVXptfUEhWGR0bEA7LZ1DU3ZrQoj3cG9Jf2SAwCUtqhexMjsHOYAzFg0IQDUAPpuAEoAKkdC2G5yp9hHoQDyRwDqAIKnoQCSoQDiQhMGneOz2M2OZ0u11u90eLwAIthlPc3O9ztggSCzLtMPtMBCLnDQkJzvC3HCjojkTc0RjgTtgshvFgDiZtm4AG6YBwkNl0rHbRnM/FstzIBDEASoPmYhkMJleFmi4iGdCoFgy%2BnYoWKkXspyTYiYViakHA4IEA5qgjKSXoLwOUKod4ANQAGhA0AxJgdJugQCAuTziKKLTKzAA2A5B1oHL0%2Bv0BoNEEP6wThqNBsyLWUDKzAg6Fg4AemLBzcYmQXgMBHx1oOiTtDstXlSRl9eBYiXoB34xAOtFQqESCkxRYOFqtqBtTYcrO28IOGjZ%2Bfe477BwgiZAqQAXpgjpa8PPF8vthYJ/O3NHuVwAHR7zAQHPn1mWax4HMFosmPNj8dFtatoYM2b5WAuN7IFwJgAKwWHgsGLgAVJBZiwfBiErv%2Bha/vCsrfoWRoEGsDBTjOIEOFh9IDHh9JaoK8rClenYsBaxDBHeCCmpipYHAAYl48rVAcRBxpW1ZMLWIkIHW04NrOlqoFQIkAO6oJBKYKAcrbBMAByum6E6COx3p4Mgo7moIZHAfaDgGZ6AgJgQ/qBtyKahum2wYpGkGxvGlrbsmvJpgQGaoV%2BIJ/gRJZltg3prPiBAyR2%2B4HEpGkkFpeBaUwBwsNWjjdvi6VxJuj5pcpBkHEawDZbWxAReO26PoeKV6ouMYPng%2B7PlRa5Fs13UHpaTAcqoQhDSebUlgcpUoXEfXYTFBzfAwaRiJNHL1HgTARPQWkblVw7RJJ6QWf1hZHEcLBmDBEbHgoPhTddN13UcSgEPukrvXgt0Rr1574Rdy3KNEfYsPp7pkfJFGhdFG5bs5AYtUeU1nhex6igco3jUNK6XtYbKLnEjU/lFwPjldr33b5RyJF0z0sNTRyDkw9o/X9EBGha0SNpgBBHKIkyiv5xzXX9eBIXyEDmBGMboQhMHwosL6rgBRZUxLqF0wzRPHEzf0s6gbNeBzd1c5gPPEHzAtC6F7Ki5rd2S9LstZgriEq316uFo9EN6y9hts%2BgRyYIkeDbGYW4%2BKQ%2BvM/ltCDqH4eRxAMY6w0sdZhnBBe4D0W4UD468UIT1JfiRosEwwS6QclSYGwghaTp7YKKIBj9sdKrVOd46Tkaj20KFcELUr3sawbb2TCQmCm6knPc4IvNEYLTDC%2ByTv3VLXkW4Puex37qtLZOQEKVNA8Fehy5K2B1WYHv6HQTf1h3w/cFoc/liv5fcHbIht8XyHuhSQ/8X6AOHhYGCoCv7gPQhGaBF5YFwQGJhfOZpgYlzLslSu1c1rtnro3Agzc2x6TbmIeoaVEgnR7ktBGg19ytUxhBHGE19z4yYdeR8%2BNCaWE/EtX8asfan1hmBPW8s4KK2QqhD2Y80HjkLnRYGRESLWQUotGiQNApuWCm4MMXkDjAEYNQzApxVTqhdNo4giMXIozahFARS0tHBg8vbbA1UzEsAsc4uRRYVQMDVJ4yxd4B7RC5FuIaR9FFNSRiAPxASjhYA5GZCu6Bx6%2BxiSwAgXAACc2TtgDAMYwLm6BnyROBtuQSeBwZHAtAkuq7EIheGqC4vkVp6l4EadUCAsYuAaA0GU2hJAyoxNsUw087CrxtW4e%2BXhpMcLkx9u4/x5igmJFbAgI4EQmDIAANYQHwIaDpTT0jQEYHnQR8zaLoPHMo4gpE4krO8auBR6DJxV2CL1aiFzlpCCocgKpABPaS%2BJyrpXLksgJGViC9wGiMoarUgrEFYe1A4vT0bHysoQahZ0ppor6X0tJy0/hGO7olNSEL1RQpheklyiKWn6MRVwKahiQiktMcswJwY06WORWU6JtLLH0rcYiswzKSWSRMR4rxKZuXBl5YtaKvEACyxpHpGhEp2fEG56yNhESpQgCBIZugxZacBBlCVMCaepSYXQqp623OKSUDBUABgQHgYAGyB6eGOQIQWg5dkBmdSpAG3yEaTjGUuCZWMsXdzOuwnhFg5kATNVDPWwjbIEHsoyrOljsyEtLCmwyabpw2WbAZGCXAo7ZqhXmnxhZLWiVcHaiCDqJRSlde6z199vXVD9agANIAg0hscTEx17aQD2ljQIUUaovB7UwK0ydp0BDNsXE2qGABaX0UxzVoJNd/IeTpd3fIbdaqYR7U0ttHW251HaPVHC9d4XtTJ%2B07MDagYNfKixhsxWjKN7IJz1WXd6eNMzE1LRuffAqF6i0QXTc2GDsqUyxhFV%2B%2BtVq67%2BJg1NVtTqXUgDdfex9PqGB9oHUOtD26XJjtvROtYwGZ2rHnYu%2Bj1RsN61cNhrdNqGgwYVRgss8JsrdiYEC8F4Dsb%2BI1WwESTAdmMBHdR1YlpRRY3MGYeEcldUZoOPqpKymjUgDfKK1TAHwHsfZFjbcrhaCEodQZ0z151PnE1bJ%2BTpE9MIAMwZIz6mrxYyXWx507o7xoEEgQZ8/mAN%2BaUF6dAo4zAmcswB6z/jbN7sUUtXiQmFAibE9gqDQ9JPoGk4lOTCnor2aaVFpziXNOWm06BTzhnjM1YPZmy9bgrMxJs3Z0dDnku1bMC5mTdR3O6YNS1vzjmrSsfSAZULqxBCRZmzF7kAh4vTcG1RgMvWMvXN8fzFR6LqLwg4MsWgnAYK8D8BwLQpAXUcC62B30qx1gimxDwUgBBNDneWG%2B7YME7ySGyb0z7kgK2SG2HEGC%2BhOCSBu79h7nBeAKBABob7v3lhwFgEgNAXY6DRHIJQfH4d6AxA5MgRIiQjgchyUcfJRxVARmkDQIe0Q0cQAiEjiIwR6gAs4F93nzBiAAqeBEbQblBe8Hx4Qp4DBaAC7u7wLAjTgAVkTmj7gKuG6GGAOIZXpB8BGgcHgLkWv7uYFUNyJpmwvs80u4b2gHSVSi48FgJHBB2IsGl8sKgBhgAKBdHgTAKknhUNu19/gggRBiHYFIGQghFAqHUIb3QZh9B65QAm/QHS0eQGWMOHunAN1PFFRu14YhaAHF4KgLkxB2JYHz8%2BNobl0guH8WMFopBAgzGKKUHIKQ0gCC74PvI6Qej9/6BMeupuBCdFGN68Yre581CmJPvoMQJhTFH9vroG%2B5hb%2BWAoN7GwJAXau4jw3j2DjM8kHlBQlPow5LvPkzcuBCBDJ2FwRYvAfvK5VlIBkjZn6BbwB3vC4AGDuihxgjMC4FgLMDiESzhw4AR1IFu3u0e1R3R0xwANIBx0QBQHVDJyJwoAcgJ3J0DCpxpzp2yQZwGCZxZz4DoHqk5250N2F352l1IE4NF3F0lwcG4Nl0YAIHl0VyR1Vy8HVyry1y%2BywCriMAN3u2Nzb3NyRytxt1rG4IdyR2dwiFdwBXd02Huy907F9z4ADyDxDzDwj24Oj2EHbnj1Z1kGTzUCR10FaAMCMGzzA1zwiGb0L0SGLw4FL3L0r0ThLHqHFBAAMjMFr3r0b3vngGP1n2qA73cCX2717yKE3wkHiASFyGHwyEyLHyKIPwHykDiASDsDb3nx3xKJn3aDqP3z71yMqL30XyyG7x42mByMPzyLiB/xWDWDPyGMd2u3QKRxvzvwfyf1oNfwKQgA/xTDfG2B/z/yx3%2BxAG2G2Ffx2P2IOIOJQLQIwNrxR1sBwP/y0EAMdziMmOv3OKuL%2B1IHr1SGcEkCAA%3D)**): MSVC "optimizes" the vector store to an array + scalar element access into into shuffles like `vextractf128 xmm0, ymm2, 1` / `vpextrd eax, xmm2, 1` / `add ebx, eax` when you compile with `-arch:AVX2`. Yes, repeating the same `vextractf128` for all four elements of the high half.  Or worse without that, using `vextractf128 xmm0, ymm2, 1` / `vpsrldq xmm0, xmm0, 4` / `vmovd   eax, xmm0` (although that's still the same amount of shuffle uops; `vpextrd r, x, imm` is a 2 uop instruction.  https://uops.info/)  Store and scalar reload would be faster for accessing each element one at a time.   **But either way is slower than an efficient hsum with manual shuffling.**

See `hsum_8x32` in *[Fastest method to calculate sum of all packed 32-bit integers using AVX512 or AVX2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60108658/fastest-method-to-calculate-sum-of-all-packed-32-bit-integers-using-avx512-or-av)* (and *[Fastest way to do horizontal SSE vector sum (or other reduction)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996764/fastest-way-to-do-horizontal-sse-vector-sum-or-other-reduction)* in general) for how to horizontally sum a vector of `int32_t` elements.  As always, shuffle the high half down to line up with the low half for `_mm_add_epi32`, narrowing until you're down to 1 element<sup>2</sup>.

MSVC's auto-vectorized code `dotProductNoAVX` uses a vectorized horizontal sum that's not as efficient as it could be, especially for E-cores (using `vphaddd ymm` which is 2 shuffle + 1 add uop on P-cores, or twice that on E cores since it foolishly doesn't reduce to 128-bit vectors as the first step.)

MSVC also auto-vectorizes your scalar cleanup loop, not realizing that it only runs 0..7 iterations.  This doesn't cost much, just an extra branch to skip the vectorized version, but one way to work around that is to make it more obvious to the compiler that the loop range is small, just `size%8`.

```
    // Sum the remaining elements using scalar operations
    // MSVC realizes this shouldn't vectorize, unlike the previous version
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < size%8; ++i) {
        dotProduct += vec1[avxSize+i] * vec2[avxSize+i];
    }
```

**Also, doing a 16-byte vector as part of the cleanup can be worth it, saving 4 scalar iterations.**  For your element count of 100, `100 % 8` is 4, so there's exactly 1 `__m128i` vector left after doing 12x `__m256i` vectors.  `100 % 16 == 4` as well, so unrolling your main loop by 2 vectors wouldn't create extra cleanup work if your actual use-case is vectors of exactly 100 elements.

You can fold this final 128-bit vector into the horizontal-sum part of the cleanup by adding it in after you've reduced the main loop's result down to one `__m128i`.

```
// dot product of two vectors using AVX2 intrinsics
// optimized for small sizes
// UNTESTED
int dotProductAVX(const std::vector<int>& vec1, const std::vector<int>& vec2)
{
    // Ensure the size of vectors is a multiple of 8 (size of AVX register)
    std::size_t size = vec1.size();
    std::size_t avxSize = size / 8 * 8;

    // Perform AVX dot product
    __m256i sum = _mm256_setzero_si256();
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < avxSize; i += 8)
    {
        __m256i vec1_part = _mm256_loadu_si256(reinterpret_cast<const __m256i*>(&vec1[i]));
        __m256i vec2_part = _mm256_loadu_si256(reinterpret_cast<const __m256i*>(&vec2[i]));
        sum = _mm256_add_epi32(sum, _mm256_mullo_epi32(vec1_part, vec2_part));
        // optionally unroll; also change i+=16 and avxSize calc
        // and improve the cleanup with either a __m128i or __m256i loop
        // vec1_part = _mm256_loadu_si256(reinterpret_cast<const __m256i*>(&vec1[i+8]));
        // vec2_part = _mm256_loadu_si256(reinterpret_cast<const __m256i*>(&vec2[i+8]));
        //sum = _mm256_add_epi32(sum, _mm256_mullo_epi32(vec1_part, vec2_part));
        // clang will unroll this loop for us
    }

    __m128i sum128 = _mm_add_epi32( 
                 _mm256_castsi256_si128(sum),
                 _mm256_extracti128_si256(sum, 1));

    std::size_t cleanupSize = size%8;
    if (cleanupSize >= 4) {
            __m128i v1 = _mm_loadu_si128(reinterpret_cast<const __m128i*>(&vec1[avxSize]));
            __m128i v2 = _mm_loadu_si128(reinterpret_cast<const __m128i*>(&vec2[avxSize]));
            sum128 = _mm_add_epi32(sum128, _mm_mullo_epi32(v2, v1));
            //cleanupSize -= 4; // stops MSVC and clang from realizing cleanupSize is less than 1 vector
            avxSize += 4;
    }
    int dotProduct = hsum_epi32_avx(sum128);
    cleanupSize = size % 4;  // keep it super simple so compilers still don't auto-vectorize the final cleanup
    // Sum the remaining elements using scalar operations
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < cleanupSize; ++i)
    {
        // clang goes nuts with this, spending tons of instructions on maskload
        // and another hsum.  MSVC just unrolls it with some branching
        dotProduct += vec1[avxSize+i] * vec2[avxSize+i];
    }

    return dotProduct;
}
```

See how it compiles on [**Godbolt**](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIAOwAzKSuADJ4DJgAcj4ARpjEIJIAnKQADqgKhE4MHt6%2BehlZjgLhkTEs8Ykptpj2JQxCBEzEBHk%2BfkG19TlNLQRl0XEJSakKza3tBVy2EwMRQ5UjKQCUtqhexMjsHOaBWDSRANQA%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%2BSLG2bKjrVQKh4cR1MSAK9sImALLPTMYSCE4308GQdHhYrUdHHYw90H7Eh/Qa1phLSLx8uxacQPnAhsu9AQkwIQNg15NNw0zQIsWjaD40Ta1d1l9M3AjX3zGzXkKdo9dJ0i7BfU2QkocJZ8jkl6C0wKvACva2tHF7Qks/07cM6z7KjhNYA8/rYgTMnXdnxkjO8YDp88EPV9Kabt2gxb611NUIQu4NZcM4rMu0P0yn%2Bsi5QEgHFhlZy0WHfWnSzDgqNsZX9unO3qMDryw9pVZo%2Be7W8ytx3fu9zHmTT3bi8r2fzkjmH0fDzC5/Pyg/Sjc/xmSpuFDaR9TxxhOO5C2B9JpHxOMOaaXgL47wgCaK0CRmx5ROKIcY4og4DQgShAUEAo5xkwkhOCiIAa925uAnekCY7QP6ONQ%2BO9EGoGQagqM6DMCYOINggguCmD4M5IQhhu8SG%2BzIdGHMlDkK0OvqAoCI02HwI4dNWaSk2YjWCuw4%2BLBazDmJhAKBMCCDBRzCw1oSj47c0ivrHIYhaAVUKgwaUtBaBhTEAoRGkpDDAEJEhf%2BiIuAxgSl/MeCZqz9QThWBK3YxaZTTgmeghgvAQzqlDJG9UEifwGljTOg5JGnmHKOOJwMKzmNYXAlgCCkGOh4XwgRQiRFiIlC7a0pTpEfXIfeBRlhZ7ULsZU4skVrEWPUfUjhjSUFZEvhgwQWCSLtIIAQrpRDGG9NkVGeRCEQkWGGTQwGYyeZqLqQgrRpi9F0wQUYrxqBTE1NaFY5hFjRnmXiWkwJtU6C0HcZ4gFUM85DhHBDLc7Z%2Br4UIiozGQ1/Q%2BCstMwm2jlIXXZF87mQEDFrIWRwrIVl2ZrDOdiu5HDMCqHVh5RwLN8W8Nuf9U5DEVHN0ftaFkpoGCZO/uPLsP9t6z2UZOPAUtvTpO5WkXli4sRQUkCsdkICyUlnhdZLkXAUVzNZkSpZ9c2l4PWeIzZqq8A7P6TBTCUSf4jOZSo7FJrYyqzqZw7hhKDItOWYI1ZBqNm%2Bm6ZZIaZq5Ex0tRpXlijbXKuLCNZFzrrk6IujGgy%2BiCYPJMQmhaXIvqxiZXQ5V5ZOUZKldE6K7dJBhUiuMUcBUbpCDdLeBKLJflUGlCvE0Ygu6KzSVynl0TQX0AUAVKGhgjgatDqSksVqxShKOOW4VwDBYisEBRUCjoFztzkgpDNakNLsyspGkshbJXSvbm3bes6wo8yOJ5TASkpzB0yfkrIPY%2Bx%2BITJqZS9BiAFXGP8mcDAwAcCHtbVA0VQ7RNSYcMQ3ai3zwrEIHwkNobVxRkwCIXbkao3yoVDsSsFCiAMIOOKaoGg603KbO%2B7tB7Xhfr/G8MHj1jzCtYL8QC8JKocRWJtnZgCoEwAVbl2HskICQ3nYKCg0iuC7UQX0mcpYRDSg4HIBUBBHBYKIzyjSzmRUiUlNOg5N0sAfMWWt9ajjaHbG2DxnhaC52tMJ/0mpCSxDVIqHyRgzn23FhBduFCEJTq/MhI4aF9kWAC5YKhBF53scFv1GmxByJebXYa9cMKWUh09vyDMhrsBHCCZEEjmBzjqk1G6TLxBKMD3ZfyzAJl/z2Ojffcd2WBTVxKywMroY81tYYBqDr5WHwmiUMQHkO4x62v6ruVzfWThYC5FrQkxB0Ddd3CwAgXBkjJECP4PLjB0HoFfAexr7tXKipIM5K0s266cViNbHI3scs2mu3gW7DQIDxi4BoDQE2b4UbZYeJ%2B41X40Y/s%2BZjn4ItscVQ1oC03SsDatodE4sQPKeQgPgY0L27sCGgIwT5Ki0tC0nPF8icP%2BtdeUYT22y71MRB7nHODRwhCSeQKKtxqSK5S1SWT7OctJv32o6HE9UFPuv36tOQg8VSPjVF19r73XIoAkYFL1OCMet9d59%2B/n7tmvhx9rl0OGr275ZV8V3r8PQxmPK7yo7/omvlYe610OTqoIm8K2bvrnW0xW9DDbue5lIo3VNPJE0kNuyEi3OvbzDnsri%2BXUNwusfoufxA3b/oVdT330lNKJKQYfLAAQCcIbnhscMFwcOLyQYko1SvjD2%2BEugd0fFPeqXynf4scsFD4n/HE%2BenGkl1sTtDdvNDBTZP5YE%2B0Edn39uA%2BHDZTgnpH3aZ4zO9t0wVPrgM9QV3NnmUee8AF6L/xkvDRy%2BoEryAavtftdBj37nkAjoSP3c5BqLwsR6CtafwJHI2/lxb772ijT1aCT1S3MmnEnwIBdFAP6g3yIGAKgNdBnx3yzylH3xAHz0L2L28DPxZAv08ir1QBr1t3r2XXfnPCbw/kl2fxdnbwhwsC72ph7yn2gOQOXDn0QKH3K1X3KzHxhzgMRlcFYJykz3dnv1QAPyP2wNL3P0v2v1t13zQIf2/waHFDfw/0wC/02B/wEGEPGiEKQJyiAP4laGEP9xUUikRDzl7CYHZ2Q0gM/l6zDzYEhiYBvQYFvxQEahvGb3MDMERFnCbAdj%2BShm8OyhAA/BdzcGb0gL0PFGb13FcG8WT1328PiI/j8MuHD1cPcJCIamtlXgiL8J8I/hUJyGEIfDQFcgIFfBKNvGKKUB9HQHHDMCiISPviSPMNhW%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%2Bl4ExNtIBlIFxLMAfCjCkE%2B0CECGSHJKjDRKjDgmpI4FpNIChJhLhKZJZLZNQtIE5MQC8N5K/QFOdlYpGG42AC4FJJmEVPrhVLVK9L1K1LNNIFEoNKNJNIcHEotMYAICtNcXpPtK8EdJcRdPRKwHUw9J2BhJ9LnP9PpKDJrHrHEvDPpKjLVANNjL0uQs4hYCTL4AMDTIzKzJzMYHEoLOEAIxLOkG8orLUHpN0C%2BjrOMEbP0BexbNfFhLSFI07O7KOF7P7OinUy2B4iXFUH0ijGijsjA0CDHJ5GIEnP42nJvLPL8AgFcFfJCF6w/I3JmCKG3NyCvOXPSC3IaHquPPKoaAvLaFar0FPN6vvLXMfMGpfIGrfNaC6q/PWGRL/LIohMovpOAqypyrGm4tHX8AJIfA1QgDgrTFRKQvoq0DQtxMCGgrwquuuuurIooqorHMZNsDopQtOv/I4FHOWqAqeteuxNICKqyGcEkCAA%3D%3D%3D), much more efficiently:

```
... subtract one pointer from another so only one needs an indexed addr mode
$LL4@dotProduct:                            ;; The main loop, still not unrolled
        vmovdqu ymm1, YMMWORD PTR [rax]                 ; 1 uop
        vpmulld ymm1, ymm1, YMMWORD PTR [rdx+rax]       ; 3 uops
        lea     rax, QWORD PTR [rax+32]                 ; 1 uop
        vpaddd  ymm2, ymm1, ymm2                        ; 1 uop
        sub     rcx, 1                                  ; macro-fused with JNE
        jne     SHORT $LL4@dotProduct                   ; 1 uop

$LN3@dotProduct:
        movzx   eax, r9b
        and     al, 7                         ; size % 8
        vextracti128 xmm0, ymm2, 1
        vpaddd  xmm3, xmm0, xmm2              ; sum128 = first step of hsum

        cmp     al, 4
        jb      SHORT $LN44@dotProduct        ; if (cleanupSize < 4) goto skip last __m128
        vmovdqu xmm1, XMMWORD PTR [rbx+rdi*4]
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rsi]          ; Maybe reloading a std::vector begin or end pointer?  I didn't look at the whole function
        vpmulld xmm1, xmm1, XMMWORD PTR [rax+rdi*4]
        vpaddd  xmm3, xmm1, xmm3              ; sum128 += 
        add     rdi, 4                        ; avxSize += 4

$LN44@dotProduct:
        xor     r14d, r14d
        and     r9d, 3                        ; cleanupSize = size % 4
        mov     r10d, r14d
        mov     r11d, r14d
        vpunpckhqdq xmm0, xmm3, xmm3          ; hsum_epi32_avx
        vpaddd  xmm2, xmm0, xmm3
        vpshufd xmm1, xmm2, 177
        vpaddd  xmm0, xmm1, xmm2
        vmovd   r8d, xmm0                     ; scalar int dotProduct

    ... then 0 to 3 scalar imul
```

So the total shuffling to get `int dotProduct = sum(vector)` was only 3 shuffles and 3 vector adds, vs. 4x2 (high 128) + 4 (low 128) shuffles plus 8x `vmovd` + 7x scalar `add` from `result[0] + result[1] + ...` because of how badly MSVC did with that.

BTW, clang also auto-vectorizes `dotProductNoAVX`, unrolling by 4 vectors so it's doing 32 elements per loop iteration.  But its only cleanup is a scalar loop after hsumming the vector result, so could be doing as many as 31 iterations of scalar `imul`.  That would be fine for 100 elements since `100 % 32 == 4`, but would be much worse for size = 95.

---

**Footnote 1: benchmarking methodology**
In general to make a robust benchmark, you might try `++vector1[80 + (i&16)]` to make the data different every time.  (Modifying a later element means it will hopefully not still be in the store buffer when the dot product is doing a vector load, otherwise you'll get a store-forwarding stall.)  On GNU C compilers, `asm("" :: "r"(vector1.data() : "memory")` would be a good way to tell the compiler that vector data might have changed.

Either way, assign the result to `volatile int resultAVX;` or use something like `Benchmark::DoNotOptimize()` to force the compiler to materialize it in a register inside the loop instead of only doing the calculation for the final repeat loop whose result is actually used.

See also *[Idiomatic way of performance evaluation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60291987/idiomatic-way-of-performance-evaluation)* re: those considerations and other things like warm-up effects.

---

**Footnote 2:** Or reduce down to 64-bit before moving to scalar for the last add.  The final step can be `vmovq rax, xmm0` / `rorx rcx, rax, 32` / `add eax, ecx`.  But MSVC apparently doesn't know how to emit `rorx` for rotates even though it will use other BMI2 instructions like `shlx` for `x << y`, so it's probably not worth trying to get MSVC to emit optimal asm that puts less pressure on the three vector execution ports.  That would be useful if you're doing a lot of separate dot products.

Actually, with lots of separate dot products, you could reduce 8x `__m256i` down to 8 results by shuffling them together, instead of just reducing each one separately.  Like `vphaddd` with two separate inputs to reduce 2 vectors down to 1.  (That's 2 shuffle + 1 add uop per `vphaddd`, so it's only worth using for cases like this).  You'd start with 2x `vperm2i128` (`_mm256_permute2x128_si256`) to feed one `_mm256_add_epi32`.