# Run AVX SIMD instruction in VScode on Windows with a WSL

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, simd, avx, altivec

I have just started to learn about SIMD. I use VScode to try what I learn. I wanna try an example thay goes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <altivec.h>

int a[4] __attribute__((aligned(16))) = { 1, 3, 5, 7 };
int b[4] __attribute__((aligned(16))) = { 2, 4, 6, 8 };
int c[4] __attribute__((aligned(16)));

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    __vector signed int *va = (__vector signed int *) a;
    __vector signed int *vb = (__vector signed int *) b;
    __vector signed int *vc = (__vector signed int *) c;

    *vc = vec_add(*va, *vb);    // 1 + 2, 3 + 4, 5 + 6, 7 + 8

    printf("c[0]=%d, c[1]=%d, c[2]=%d, c[3]=%d¥n", c[0], c[1], c[2], c[3]);

    return 0;
}
```

When I run it in my WSL I write:

```
gcc exercice.c -o main && ./main
```

But I get the error message:

```
fatal error: altivec.h: No such file or directory
```

I have tried with diferent things such as using "-march=native", headerfiles: immintrin.h and x86intrin.h. But no luck. With CPU-Z I can see my CPU support AVX and AVX2 instructions.

Is there something I'am missing?

Comment: Altivec is a PowerPC instruction set...

Comment: So what do I have to do in order to make my code work?

Comment: Use AVX intrinsics.

Comment: AVX1 / AVX2 intrinsics are in `<immintrin.h>`, like `__m256i va  = _mm256_loadu_si256(const __m256i*)a);` and `_mm256_storeu_si256( (__m256i*)c,  _mm256_add_epi32( va, vb ));`.  That's AVX2 using 256-bit (32 byte) vectors of 8 `int`s.  AVX1 integer code using 128-bit vectors uses the same intrinsics as SSE, again `#include <immintrin.h>`

Comment: [How does SIMD (avx) processing work? for example, if I want 10 32 bit floats how do i fit in a 256 bit avx vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77574422) has some good simple tutorial-style examples for looping over arrays.